# Configure jacoco agent for sonar2.12 (Multi Module maven)

Tags: maven, jacoco

The Sonar latest version 2.12 has the Jacoco plugin integrated and i want to use it for my code coverage part on a multi module project.

I have a structure like this

```
proj.com.parent
   proj.com.provider
   proj,com.test
```

The Test cases for the provider project are in the test project. When i set the Code coverage plugin in sonar as jacoco it executes fine , but the combined code covergae is not presented on the DashBoard. Ihave seen a post that a single jacoco.exec file can solve the problem , but i am unable to do so.

I have tried to configure the below in my pom as below

```
<profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                          <argLine>-javaagent:${sonar.jacoco.jar}=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine> 
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${basedir}/code-coverage/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
            <sonar.jacoco.jar> C:\sonar-2.12\war\sonar-server\deploy\plugins\jacoco\META-INF\lib\org.jacoco.agent-0.5.3.201107060350.jar</sonar.jacoco.jar>
        </properties>
```

But on maven commandline " mvn clean install "  i get this error :

> Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in C:\sonar-2.12\war\sonar-server\deploy\plugins\jacoco\META-INF\lib\org.jacoco.agent-0.5.3.201107060350.jar
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   agent library failed to init: instrument

Can anyone provide any help on this ?

Answer (score 10):

the jar you are pointing to is not the jar..extract that using winrar and you will get another jar inside it. called jacocoagent.jar .to check whether you got the right jar just extract jacocoagent.jar
and look for manifest.mf and it should have an entry for premain class.

that should do.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Take a look at the [Jacoco agent artifacts at the central repository.](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.jacoco%22%20AND%20a%3a%22org.jacoco.agent%22)

There is a normal jar artifact, and there is a jar with classifier runtime. You need the "runtime" artifact to be used as agent jar. What I do, I simply download the Jacoco agent runtime jar with maven dependency plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>download-jacoco-agent</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                        <version>0.6.3.201306030806</version>
                        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                        <destFileName>jacoco-agent.jar</destFileName>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then you just need to define the following command line option:

```
<argLine>-javaagent:${project.build.directory}/jacoco-agent.jar=destfile=${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</argLine>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try setting the property **sonar.core.codeCoveragePlugin** to the value *jacoco*. The default code coverage tool in Sonar is still cobertura. See the following doco on [code coverage](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+coverage+plugins).

If that doesn't help, I found the following link (which runs Jacoco from Maven as your trying to do):

- [Separating Code Coverage With Maven, Sonar and Jacoco](http://johndobie.blogspot.com/2011/06/seperating-test-code-coverage-with.html)

Comment: yes mark , I had gone on the link you have provided and infact i got the details from the very same site. But i dont know which version of SONAR they have used and my issue is the error which is thrown runtime and i am not sure what is the exact cause.